# Selected checkbox goes to unchecked when no record founds using filterMatchMode="contains" on datatable

Tags: java, primefaces, datatable, liferay

I'm using filter on datable and have used all filterMatchMode. When i filter user or enter data when records found checkbox remains as before in list but when no records found then checkbox goes to unchecked.Code is given below:

```
<p:dataTable widgetVar="usersTable" id="recieverUserList"
    reflow="true" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="430"
    value="#{UserReciepentController.recieverVo.reciepentList}"
    var="user" styleClass="ptable" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

    <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:40%;"
        filterBy="#{user.recieverName}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <div>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.recieverName}" />
        </div>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Email" style="width:50%;"
        filterBy="#{user.recieverEmail}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <div>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.recieverEmail}" />
        </div>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Designation" style="width:40%;"
        filterBy="#{user.recieverDesignation}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <div>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.recieverDesignation}" />
        </div>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Location" style="width:20%;"
        filterBy="#{user.location}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <div>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.location}" />
        </div>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Department" style="width:20%;"
        filterBy="#{user.recieverListName}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <div>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.recieverListName}" />
        </div>
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="width:40%;">
        <div>
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{user.userSelected}" />
        </div>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Don't know if I understood correctly, but how can you have entries inside your dataTable if you say no records have been found?

Comment: i've entries and list is populated but when records not found on filter then checked checkbox goes to unchecked otherwise filter working fine.

Comment: It is obvious that if the records list is empty, then `#{user.userSelected}` will resolve to `null` because `user` will be null. Hence, the checkbox is not getting checked for ***No record(s) found.***

Comment: thanks brother i've done.